# How can you choose 4 distinct items from 5 things and get a repetition?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am very confused about this question.

You have a set of 5 letters {a,b,c,d,e} and you need the number of four letter strings that do not contain aa in the middle.

This is 5 choose 4, but if you are choosing less items than the number that exist and all are distinct how can you possibly end up with a "aa" anywhere?

Comment: I think every $4$ letter word with letters from the alphabet $\{a,b,c,de\}$ is fair game, for example $aaaa$

Comment: Where in the question does it *ever* say anything about choosing 4 distinct items?  It just says "four-letter strings".  The letters are *distinguished*, in the sense that they are not sitting unordered in a bag but one can refer to the first letter or the second letter as specific parts of the string.  But why do you think they are distinct?  Just because they *could* be chosen distinctly (because $4 < 5$) doesn't mean that they are!

Comment: The start of the list:  aaba, aabb, aabc, aabd, aaca, aacb, aacc, aacd, aada, aadb, aadc, aadd, abaa, abab, abac, abad, abba, abbb, abbc, abbd, abca, abcb, abcc, abcd, acaa, ...  Note that each letter may be used multiple times and there are many more than just $\binom{5}{4}=5$ arrangements.  Approach via multiplication principle and/or inclusion exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unrestricted, you have $5$ choices for each place in the string, hence $5^4$ strings.

By "middle" I take it to be the central two, so strings like $-aa-$ are banned.
The other $2$ places could be filled in $5^2$ ways,

hence valid number of strings $= 5^4 - 5^2$

Answer (score 1):

There are $5^2-1$ options for the two letters in the middle and then $5^2$ options for the letters in the edges. So there are $(5^2-1)\times5^2=24\times 25=600$ words.

Comment: I am trying to understand this, can you explain why 5^2 -1 and how you end up with 5^4?

Comment: @Dre_Dre  There are five choices for each entry.  Hence, if there were no restrictions, we could fill the two middle entries in $5^2$ ways.  Since we are not allowed to use aa, the number of ways we can fill the two middle entries is $5^2 - 1$.

Comment: What does the 1 represent?

Comment: It represents the question for which you give the answer to problem $1$, so for example the sequence $1,2,3,4$ meanas you got it all correct.