# Suppose the alphabet consists of just {a,b,c,d,e}. How many 4-letter strings are there that do not have “aa” in the middle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose the alphabet consists of just {a,b,c,d,e}. 
How many 4-letter strings are there that do not have “aa” in the middle?

I so far answered:
We assume that a word could have multiple same letters.

Since the word is only four letters, a can not be in the second and third position.

We look at this as a can be in either the second or third position.

Accoringly: (all combos with no a in second or third position) + all combos with a in second but not third + a in third but not second.

[C(5,1)*C(4,1)*C(4,1)*C(5,1)]  + [C(5,1)*C(1,1)*C(4,1)*C(5,1)] + [C(5,1)*C(4,1)*C(1,1)*C(5,1)]
=400+100+100
=600

Therefore, there are 600 4-letter strings of (a,b,c,d,e) that don't have aa in the middle.

Would that be correct, or incorrect in this case!

Thanks,
A

Comment: How many strings are there?  How many *DO* have "aa" in the middle?  If you add the strings that do and the strings that don't what do you get?

Comment: There are 5x5x5x5=625 letters altigether.  There are 5x1x1x5=25 that have both "aa" in the middle.  So there are 625-25=600 that don't.  Or your way works too.

Comment: Does `aaeb` count as "having `aa` in the middle", or is it only strings like `caae`?

Comment: As an aside, using binomial coefficients for these is incredibly tedious.  Why write `C(5,1)*C(4,1)*C(4,1)*C(5,1)` when you could instead write $5\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 5$.  You don't always have to think in terms of binomial coefficients, regular numbers are useful too and more compact to say aloud and write.

Comment: Linking to [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1881821/how-can-you-choose-4-distinct-items-from-5-things-and-get-a-repetition).  I knew the problem was familiar, but couldn't find the link at the time.  The specific issue that each poster was facing were different, so I personally feel they can remain separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the first letter and the last letter of the string as one of the $5$ letters in the alphabet. This gives you $5^2=25$ options. For the second and third letter, out of the possible $5^2$ letter pairs, "aa" is forbidden. Thus, you have $5^2-1=24$ options for the middle letters. This leaves you with a total of $25*24=600$ strings.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's easier to calculate the complement then subtract it from the total. i.e the answer is the number of words with $aa$ in the middle subtracted from the total number of words.

Clearly the number of words with $aa$ in the middle is the same as the number of $2$ letter words - $5^2$. Hence the answer you're looking for is
$$5^4 - 5^2 = 600.$$

So yes your final answer is correct!